# Can Kmeans total within sum of squares increase with number of clusters?

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means

I am seeing an increase in total within Sum of squares when I am using below code.Is this even possible or I am doing some mistake in code?

```
v<-foreach(i = 1:30,.combine = c)  %dopar%  {
  iter <- kmeans (clustering_data,centers = i,iter.max = 1000)
  iter$tot.withinss
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

K-means is a randomized algorithm. It does not guarantee to find the optimum.

So you simply had a bad random.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. See Anony-Mousse's answer.

If you used the `nstart = 25` argument of the `kmeans()` function, you would run the algorithm 25 times, let R collect the error measures from each run, and build averages internally. This way you do not need to construct a foreach-loop.

from the documentation of R's `kmeans()`

```
## random starts do help here with too many clusters
## (and are often recommended anyway!):
(cl <- kmeans(x, 5, nstart = 25))
```

*You* have to choose a reasonable value for nstart. Then, errors by different random initializations are more likely to have averaged out. (But there is no guarantee that tot.withinss is minimal after nstart runs.  )